# Вылезает ошибка, как исправить

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.json:json:20090211 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.loginpage"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app_id: "34668d75-ec07-4364-bf6c-666a0f052ec5",
                                onesignal_google_project_number: "392170532113"]
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    compile 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:+'
    compile 'com.neovisionaries:nv-websocket-client:1.31'
    compile "org.java-websocket:Java-WebSocket:1.3.0"
    compile 'io.socket:socket.io-client:0.8.3'
    compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.+@aar'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:+'
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:+"
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: Попробуй поставить compile и targetSdkVersion последние (25).

Comment: На этот вопрос уже есть ответ.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32921328/dependency-org-jsonjson20090211-is-ignored-for-debug-as-it-may-be-conflicting

Comment: @Сергей непомогает